# Apache issue? Default WordPress .htaccess rewrites causes redirect to the AlmaLinux (9.1) default page

Tags: linux, wordpress, .htaccess, apache2.4

I could really do with some help here please. I think this is an Apache issue rather than a WordPress issue.
If I allow .htaccess to process rewrites on my Wordpress sites by adding `AllowOverride FileInfo` to the https conf file, my WordPress sites all redirect to the AlmaLinux default page.
**What is going on here?**

Here is httpd.conf:

```
    ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
    Listen *:80 http
    Include conf.modules.d/*.conf
    User apache
    Group apache
    ServerAdmin root@localhost
    ServerName mrtesty.net
    
    <Directory />
        AllowOverride none
        Require all denied
    </Directory>
    
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
    
    <Directory "/var/www">
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    
    <Directory "/var/www/html">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    
    <IfModule dir_module>
        DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php
    </IfModule>
    
    <Files ".ht*">
        Require all denied
    </Files>
    
    ErrorLog "logs/error_log"
    LogLevel warn
    
    <IfModule log_config_module>
        LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
        LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
        <IfModule logio_module>
            LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
        </IfModule>
        CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
    </IfModule>
    
    <IfModule alias_module>
        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"
    </IfModule>
    
    <Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    
    <IfModule mime_module>
        TypesConfig /etc/mime.types
        AddType application/x-compress .Z
        AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
        AddType text/html .shtml
        AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
    </IfModule>
    
    AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
    
    <IfModule mime_magic_module>
        MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
    </IfModule>
    
    EnableSendfile on
    
    IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
    
    # #################
    # 
    # VirtualHosts now in     /etc/httpd/conf.d/vhosts.conf
    # SSL VirtualHosts now in /etc/httpd/conf.d/vhosts-le-ssl.conf
    # 
    # #################
    
    KeepAlive on
    TraceEnable off
```

Here is my welcome.conf that serves the AlmaLinux default page if there
is no default index page present for the root URL:

```
    <LocationMatch "^/+$">
        Options -Indexes
        ErrorDocument 403 /.noindex.html
    </LocationMatch>
    
    <Directory /usr/share/httpd/noindex>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    
    Alias /.noindex.html /usr/share/httpd/noindex/index.html
    Alias /poweredby.png /usr/share/httpd/icons/apache_pb3.png
    Alias /system_noindex_logo.png /usr/share/httpd/icons/system_noindex_logo.png
```

Here is my ssl.conf file:

```
    Listen 443 https
    SSLPassPhraseDialog exec:/usr/libexec/httpd-ssl-pass-dialog
    SSLSessionCache         shmcb:/run/httpd/sslcache(512000)
    SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300
    SSLCryptoDevice builtin
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log
        TransferLog logs/ssl_access_log
        LogLevel warn
        SSLEngine on
        SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
        SSLHonorCipherOrder on
        SSLCipherSuite PROFILE=SYSTEM
        SSLProxyCipherSuite PROFILE=SYSTEM
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mrtesty.net/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mrtesty.net/privkey.pem    
        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>
        BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
        nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
        downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
        CustomLog logs/ssl_request_log \
        "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
    </VirtualHost>
```

Here is my vhosts.conf entries for the site in question:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/www.mysite.org"
        ServerName www.mysite.org
        ServerAlias mysite.org
        <Directory "/var/www/www.mysite.org">
            AllowOverride FileInfo
            allow from all
            Options None
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =mysite.org [OR]
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.mysite.org
        RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
    </VirtualHost>
```

Here is my vhosts-le-ssl.conf entries for the site in question:

```
    <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        <VirtualHost *:443>
            DocumentRoot "/var/www/www.mysite.org"
            ServerName www.mysite.org
            ServerAlias mysite.org
            <Directory "/var/www/www.mysite.org">
    
                ###########################################
                # IF I UNCOMMENT THE BELOW OUT, IT BREAKS #
                #                                         #
     
                #AllowOverride FileInfo
    
                allow from all
                Options None
                Require all granted
            </Directory>
            Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
            SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mysite.org/fullchain.pem
            SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mysite.org/privkey.pem
        </VirtualHost>
    </IfModule>
```

And here is my WordPress site `.htaccess` file that would get processed if I uncomment `AllowOverride FileInfo` above, and then it breaks WordPress by redirecting everything to the AlmaLinux default page.

```
    # BEGIN WordPress
    # The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
    # dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
    # Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
    
    # END WordPress
```

There are other conf files but I do not see any as relevant

**Thank you so much in advance for anyone who can dig me out of this.**

Comment: Checked rewrites are enabled with: 
# httpd -M | grep rewrite ->

rewrite_module (shared)

So it's not that sadly

Comment: I can not see the point of the rewrite conditions you are checking in your vhosts.conf. You _specified_ `ServerName www.mysite.org` in there - so why would you need to _check_ what the server name was using those RewriteConds now? Did you perhaps confuse SERVER_NAME with HTTP_HOST here? The latter would be the host name actually used in the client's request.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe Those rewrites are added automatically by LetsEncrypt/certbot to each site in vhosts.conf. They redirect http to https. Note that there are numerous sites in vhosts.conf (I've just taken a sample one).
You seem to be suggesting that I don't actually need the RewriteCond statements. This may be the case but they are automatically added and I don't think they are the cause of this particular issue.

Comment: _"my WordPress sites all redirect to the AlmaLinux default page"_ - an actual, _external_ redirect? Or do you just get the content of that default page shown, without the URL changing?

Comment: If you remove the WordPress .htaccess - can you then properly access the index.php?

Comment: Confirmed I get the content of that default page shown, without the URL changing. I believe this is my welcome.conf serving the AlmaLinux default page because the server now believes there is no default index page present for the root URL. This is confirmed by me commenting out the whole welcome.conf file and then getting  "Forbidden - You don't have permission to access this resource."

Confirmed if I remove the WordPress .htaccess I can then properly access the index.php

Thus why it has worked up until now because it is not processing .htaccess but I want it to

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if this isn't Apache but something in my WordPress.

Comment: OK it is definitely an Apache issue.
I duplicated the .htaccess to another non-Wordpress site and enabled AllowOverride FileInfo and the site breaks the same way.
I also reverted and then removed the index.php from the same site and got redirected to the default page due to no default index page present for the root URL - as expected.
So there is something about my Apache setup and the default .htaccess that is causing it to no longer find index.php

Comment: OK fixed see answer below

Answer (score 0):

FIXED
I should have looked in Apache error logs in the first place.
I just did and found:

[Wed Mar 29 23:17:59.234743 2023] [rewrite:error] [pid 133333:tid 133444] [client 81.11.11.11:53583] AH00670: Options FollowSymLinks and SymLinksIfOwnerMatch are both off, so the RewriteRule directive is also forbidden due to its similar ability to circumvent directory restrictions : /var/www/www.mysite.com/

Doing a search for the error we see:
If your server is set with both FollowSymLinks and SymLinksIfOwnerMatch off, then rewrite rules will stop working

Simple as that!

So I went through all my sites in the Apache conf files and changed:

Options None

to:

Options SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

Fixed